# Add "static" search Bar below Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I made a lot of search and read many question/answer but I'm still not able to code a static search Bar below the Navigation Bar ... (in other words, a search bar stuck to the navigation Bar)

I would like something like that:

[image]

But I don't know how to do it.

This is the code I wrote:

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
      searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
      searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (navigationController?.view.bounds.size.width)!, height: 64)
      searchBar.barStyle = .default
      searchBar.isTranslucent = false
      searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
      searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
      view.addSubview(searchBar)
```

When I scroll UP, the search bar is not stuck to the navigationBar. I would like to have one block for these two parts.

Comment: You should use some constraints to pin it to the top, right?

Comment: did you use auto-layout for search bar?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Follow the step below to achieve a static `UISearchBar` under `UINavigationBar`

1. Drag `UISearchBar` on to your ViewController in Storyboard from Interface Builder.
2. Set constraints to `UISearchBar`

   - Top
   - Leading
   - Trailing
   - Fixed Height

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it in code :/ 
The second problem is that I am in a TableViewController ....

Answer (score 0):

In your interface builder (view controller in storyboard), drag `search bar` and put at desired place.

Then set for constraints like `top,leading,trailing` and `fixed height`.

and you will be able to see `search bar` stick with `navigation bar`

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it in code :/ 
The second problem is that I am in a TableViewController ....

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you check your AutoLayout & Pin 4 Constraint like image below
I hope it solve your problem.**

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it in code :/ 
The second problem is that I am in a TableViewController ....

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correct, you want to scroll screen up and down, and see your searchbar at the top anyway?
If it is what you want, you should pin your searchBar to the top using top, leading, trailing constraints. And you should add tableView or scrollView to your viewcontroller. And pin it bottom, leading, trailing to superview. And add vertical constraint between tableView (or scrollView) and searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

just add these line below : **view.addSubview(searchBar)**

```
    searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take searchcontroller and the add search bar to that search controller ,if you do like this search bar added to navigation bar while searching and give delegate and data source to search bar

```
self.searchbar.delegate = self
self.searchbar.datasource = self
```